# Application deployment doesn't work after adding QSound

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtmultimedia

I have an application that I could deploy on other machines (Visual Studio). I added the module `QtMultimedia`  to use the `QSound` class.

Wanting redeploy my app, the executable indicates me first that I need `Qt5Multimedia.dll` then `Qt5Network.dll` (which I have not added in my project).

Now my application doesn't launch, but no error message, I do not understand ...
I did not find much on the internet.

Comment: Did you add the requested dlls?

Comment: Yes, I add the two dll Qt5Multimedia.dll and Qt5Network.dll. So when I click to run the exe, nothing append.

Comment: Can you put the following code temporarily at the top of main() and see if any interesting messages get printed out to the console window when you run the program?   AllocConsole(); freopen("conout$", "w", stdout);  freopen("conout$", "w", stderr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found !

First I need to go in the folder of my exe

Then use : "windeployqt.exe ." (whithout the quotes).

That add all I need to execute my exe. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all - use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com) to list all the dependencies and make sure you have all the required dlls right besides the binary.

Next, make sure you've copied all the required plugins to the [appropriate plugin folder](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/deployment-plugins.html) besides the binary. In particulary take a look at `plugins/audio/qtaudio_windows.dll`, I think you might need to deploy it.

Also a good way to check what you app uses is to use [process explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on the machine you have no troubles on to check all the dlls it uses when the app is running.

Comment: I already used dependency walker, but it indicates me unknown dll : 
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-KERNEL32-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-PRIVATEPROFILE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-SERVICE-PRIVATE-L1-1-1.DLL
- API-MS-WIN-CORE-SHUTDOWN-L1-1-1.DLL
- EXT-MS-WIN-NTUSER-UICONTEXT-EXT-L1-1-0.DLL
- IESHIMS.DLL
..... 
I already tried add some folder in plugins (i tried to add all), but nothing work
..... 
I just try use Process explorer. I add all dll used, but no change :(

Comment: Those are of no interest to you - look at Qt librarires only. Well, if you can't determine what is the cause of it then try to run your app from the `poweshell` and look if it produces some output. Or put some `qDebug` right in the application start - it will help you in understanig on what stage it crashes.

Comment: There are no outputs (using powershell), and if I add a message at the begining of my main(), it isn't displayed

Comment: Ok, last resort I can think of: use [WinDbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/hh852365.aspx) to start you application. When it stop on `int 3` type `g` and wait until the app crashes. You will see what dlls it loads and on what stage it crashes.